# Python encoding utf error

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I am sending an email, and to send it I need to get three variables -- title, provider, and vendor_id. This is how I am getting it:

```
# # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
...
## subject
title = title.encode('utf-8')
subject = "%s - %s"%(provider, title)
msg['Subject'] = subject

## content
body_text = "The following has been successfully delivered:\n\nVendor ID: %s\nProvider: %s\nTitle: %s\n\nThank you."%((vendor_id, provider, title))
content = MIMEText(body_text, 'plain')
```

However, when I send the email the subject is encoded correctly (which includes the title), but the body_text is not (which also includes the title). This is how it looks:

```
Subject: testmovieprovider - Une soirée d'enfer

Body: The following has been successfully delivered:

Vendor ID: 02352_FR
Provider: testmovieprovider
Title: Une soirÃ©e d'enfer   <------ why is this happening?

Thank you.
```

Why is the title in the body not encoding correctly, and what would I need to change in order for it to look like the first?

**Update**: Thank you for the feedback. This is what worked:

`MIMEText(body_text, 'plain')` --> `content = MIMEText(body_text, 'plain', 'UTF-8')`

Comment: Try to add `#encoding utf-8` in top of file

Comment: How are you sending the email? Does the email have proper `Content-Type` header with `charset="utf-8"` in it?

Comment: This appears to be a text encoding problem. The trouble here is you're attempting to implicitly coerce unicode characters into ASCII when you perform your mime conversion. Have you tried some other value for `MIMEText`?

Comment: The only other thing I've tried is `content = MIMEText(body_text, 'utf-8')`, but that gives me no text at all in the email.

Comment: try `content = MIMEText(body_text, 'plain', 'utf-8')`.

Comment: @Avaris enter your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the encoding for the message:

```
content = MIMEText(body_text, 'plain', 'utf-8')
```